# How does `MonadWidget` fit to `WidgetFor`?

Tags: haskell, yesod

In Yesod there is

```hs
defaultLayout :: WidgetFor site () -> HandlerFor site Html

setTitle :: MonadWidget m => Html => m ()
```

`WidgetFor site` has an instance of `MonadWidget`. But why does `defaultLayout $ setTitle "..."` compile?

`setTitle "..." :: MonadWidget m => m ()` evaluates to *any* `MonadWidget m` (e.g. `MaybeT m` also has an instance of `MonadWidget`).

What am I missing here?

Comment: As you say, it can evaluate to `m ()` for _any_ `MonadWidget m`. So it can also provide a `WidgetFor site ()`, which is what we need to make the code compile.

Comment: Not sure, if I got you. What if `setTitle "..." :: MonadWidget m => m ()` returns another instance of `MonadWidget`? I'd understand the other way around, that is, if a function requires a `MonadWidget` as a parameter and you pass a `WidgetFor site` in. As `WidgetFor site` has an instance of `MonadWidget`. But here, we have a function that requires a `WidgetFor site` and we pass in *any* `MonadWidget`.

Comment: No, `setTitle` does not return _some_ instance it chooses, it can return _any_ instance the _caller_ chooses. All type variables like `m` in Haskell are implicitly quantified universally -- this means the caller chooses what they are. E.g. `Nothing :: Maybe a` means you can use `Nothing` where you need `Maybe Int`, choosing `a=Int`, but also where you need `Maybe String`, etc. It's a "for all m" vs "for some m" distinction, from a logical view.

Comment: I guess "[...] this means the caller chooses what they are." is the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTitle :: MonadWidget m => Html -> m ()
```

reads as the following contract between the caller and the implementation of the function

- the caller has to choose `m`
- the caller must ensure that the chosen `m` satisfies the `MonadWidget m` constraint
- the caller must pass a `Html` argument
- the function will return a value of type `m ()`

Note that it is not `setTitle` to choose `m`. The function is polymorphic (or "generic" in OOP lingo), and works at any `m` the caller chooses.

Since `defaultLayout` requires `m = WidgetFor site`, GHC infers that monad to be used at the `setTitle` call. Everything then type checks.